# PHP FTP script works by itself, but fails when part of a WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I have this really simple bit of PHP which connects via FTP to get a file. It looks like this:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$ftp_server = "xxxx";
$ftp_user = "xxxx";
$ftp_pass = "xxxx";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

if (ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) 
{
    echo "Connected successfully as $ftp_user@$ftp_server<br>\n";

    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

    if ( ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/mydir') )
    {
        echo "Changed directory successfully<br>\n";
    
        if (ftp_get($conn_id, '/full/path/to/local.file', 'remote.file', FTP_ASCII))
        {
            echo "Got file successfully. No problems here<br>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Uh oh. Problems getting file<br>\n";
            print_r(error_get_last());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Couldn't change directory<br>\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user<br>\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Creating a standalone PHP file with that in works fine. It connects, logs in and gets the files. No errors at all.

Now, I take that exact same piece of code, make no changes at all, and put it inside a WordPress plugin and it no longer works. Instead I get:

> Warning: ftp_get(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) in /path/to/file/cron.php on line xx
>
> Warning: ftp_get(): Type set to A. in /path/to/file/cron.php on line xx

I've done a lot of searching on the php_connect_nonb warning and they all suggest it's firewall related, but how can it then work when it's a standalone script.

Has anyone got any logical reasoning as to how this can be possible and why it would suddenly stop working when put into WP? I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: When you say standalone do you mean from the command line?

Comment: Did you test the plugin on the same server as the standalone code? Just to rule out any problems with the server settings.

Comment: @JMRC Both are on the same server/domain

Comment: @Dave I mean I created a test.php file in the root of the site with the exact same code in

Comment: Sorry, I confused root of the site with command line and not under the web server. Going to delete that comment now :)

Comment: Do you use different installs of XAMPP / WAMP per scenario or is there something else which might cause different mail or php.ini settings? Check whether `extension=php_ftp.dll`is added in php.ini and not commented with a `;`.Check if there's a difference between the output of the phpinfo() output.

Answer (score -1):

Check your `php.ini` file. Search for 'modules' or 'Dynamic Extensions'. Make sure the line `extension=php_ftp.dll` is among them. If you find this line, but it has a `;` in front of it, remove it, as this is used to comment lines out.

Comment: The error message comes from **within** the `ftp_get`. So the OP has php_ftp module loaded.